# Php Nested loops showing repeated values

Tags: php, html

I'm having a minute issue with nested loops.I've two tables product and product_option
Every product has an option,price 
Example Ring($25) with option red($.50) and yellow($.75).
So the table is something like this product(id,price,description) and product_option(product_id,optionname,optionprice)
When I fetch data from php the output should look something like this
Ring($25)                              total -price 25.75
red(.50),yellow(.25)

But my output shown something like this

Ring($25)
red(.50),red(.50)

Below is the code

```
session_start();
require_once './classes/cartclass.php';
 $val = new carts();

While($cartContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($cartContents)) 
 {
 if($cartContent['ctsid']==session_id())
{
 $cartid=$cartContent['ctid'];
$subTotal += $cartContent['ctprice'] * $cartContent['ctqty'];
echo  $cartContent['iname'];
echo $cartContent['mprice'];
echo  $cartContent['mdesc'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($val->getCartopt($cartid));

if($count>0){

               $CartOpt = mysql_fetch_assoc($val->getCartopt($cartid));
                foreach($CartOpt  as $Cartopts){

                    echo $CartOpts."".$CartOpt['ctopname'];
                     $i++;
                    if($i==$count)
                        break;

                  }

                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the last part of your code which made no sense at all.
Try this:

```
session_start();
require_once './classes/cartclass.php';
$val = new carts();

While($cartContent = mysql_fetch_assoc($cartContents)) 
{
    if($cartContent['ctsid']==session_id())
    {
        $cartid=$cartContent['ctid'];
        $subTotal += $cartContent['ctprice'] * $cartContent['ctqty'];
        echo  $cartContent['iname'];
        echo $cartContent['mprice'];
        echo  $cartContent['mdesc'];

        if(mysql_num_rows($val->getCartopt($cartid)) > 0) 
        {
            while ($Cartopts = mysql_fetch_assoc($val->getCartopt($cartid)))
            {
                echo $CartOpts['ctopname'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok,I already tried above one, the while gets into infinite loop.Inorder to avoid that I added a count and break in my previous code

Comment: Add a count and a break is totally useless in my honest opinion. Actually it shouldn't never fall into an infinite loop since the loop is based on results coming from a database that cannot never be endless. What i am sure of is that the foreach loop combined with mysql results and a count is equal to a simple while. while(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) will run a loop for every element of the array, so counting results and break the loop when it ends is totally useless.